# How to use socket.io-client in electron?

Tags: socket.io, electron

I'm trying to add socket.io-client to my project.

I've installed
`socket.io-client` & `@types/socket.io-client`

but I'm getting this error when I try to build:

```
/myproject/node_modules/webpack-target-electron-renderer/node_modules/webpack/lib/ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:37
TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am also having issues.

Comment: more code could help understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

node_modules is not embedeed in electron-builder package, a solution is to import all modules into the index.js entry point like describe bellow:
https://www.electron.build/tutorials/loading-app-dependencies-manually

Comment: forget about it it will not work !!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok that is working now, after long seek the problem was that you have to push your "socket.io-client" into dependencies and not devDependencies.